# How to read custom scheme url parameters in cordova android platform?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am able to read the custom url scheme params in cordova IOS using below method:

```
function handleOpenURL(url) {
 setTimeout(function() {
alert("received url: " + url);
}, 0);
}
```

How to get the same in cordova android?

Please Advice...